# Calling Cpp Project From Matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex

We Have a project called FaceTracker that is written in cpp, and we need to call it from another project written in matlab.
we`ve succeeded to call a single function from matlab using "mex" and "mexfunction" (that is written in c).
When we tried to call the full project, we added the following source file:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "FaceTracker.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
... // code
/* Call the "main" C++ subroutine. */
FaceTracker( buflen, input_buf);
}
```

and tried to compile it in matlab by typing: "mex mexFile.cpp"
But we got the following errors:

`lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\stdafx.h:13 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:4 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\stdafx.h:14 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:4 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file **"cv.h"**

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\stdafx.h:15 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:4 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file **"highgui.h"**

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\stdafx.h:16 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:4 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file **"cxcore.h"**

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\IO.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\PDM.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\CLM.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\Tracker.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:5 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file **"cv.h"**

lcc preprocessor error: C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\IO.h:44 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\PDM.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\CLM.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\Tracker.h:42 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\FaceTracker.h:5 C:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\mexFile.cpp:2 Could not find include file  `> Blockquote

How can I fix those errors?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Is opencv installed correctly?

Comment: @tr9sh.
Yes. We Succeeded to debug a "helloWorld" file, and to compile a "C" file from matlab.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to specify all of the required include paths to the mex compile function using the `-I` option, see `help mex.`  Here's an example:

```
 mex -v -g -IC:\Users\hodhod\Documents\Jam3a\PROJECT-2012!!\FindSymetryInFaces\FaceTracker\FaceTracker\SomeMissingIncludes mexFile.cpp
```

Comment: #Oli, So What do you Suggest?